# I want to give delay to the success function in the Ajax call, is it possible

Tags: jquery, ajax

I Want to give a delay time to the `success: function` of the ajax. is it possible to do that, Or not and if possible then help me how to write this?

```
  $('#subject').change(function(){
      var course_id = $('#subject').val();
      $.ajax({
          url: 'ajax/selectAssignments.php',
          type:'post',
          data: {id:course_id},
          success:function(data)
          {
               setTimeOut(2000);
               $('#data').html(data);


          }
      });
  });
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout`? (not `setTimeOut`, whatever that is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var globalVar;
 $('#subject').change(function(){
          var course_id = $('#subject').val();
          $.ajax({
              url: 'ajax/selectAssignments.php',
              type:'post',
              data: {id:course_id},
              success:function(data)
              {
                  globalVar=data;
                   setTimeout(function(){
                   $('#data').html(globalVar)},2000);    

              }
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var globlaVar;
 //$('#subject').change(function(){
          var course_id = $('#subject').val();
          $.ajax({
              url: 'ajax/selectAssignments.php',
              type:'post',
              data: {id:course_id},
              success:function(data)
              {
                  globlaVar=data;
                   setTimeout(function(){
                   console.log("timeout");
                   },2000);    

              },
              error:function(response){
              alert("error");
               setTimeout(function(){
                  console.log("timeout");
                   },2000);  
              }
          });
  //    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Use `setTimeout` as shown below

```
setTimeout(function(){
                 // Your code here
},2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var delay = 2000;
   $('#subject').change(function(){
          var course_id = $('#subject').val();
          $.ajax({
              url: 'ajax/selectAssignments.php',
              type:'post',
              data: {id:course_id},
              success:function(data)
              {
                   setTimeout(function(){
                   $('#data').html(data)},delay);    

              }
          });
      });
```